# So i have a code and it send every reply but i want it to only send a tweet is that possibile?

Tags: twitter, discord.js

So i have a code and it send every reply but i want it to only send a tweet is that possibile?
My code sends the tweet and the replies under it

This is my code it works but it doesnt do the thing:

```
var T = new Twit({
consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
access_token: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
timeout_ms: 60*1000, // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
strictSSL: true, // optional - requires SSL certificates to be valid.
})
client.once('ready', () => {
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: [process.env.TWITTER_USER_ID] })

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
//...
var url = "https://twitter.com/" + tweet.user.screen_name + "/status/" + tweet.id_str;
try {
let channel = client.channels.fetch(process.env.DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID2).then(channel => {
channel.send(**everyone Elon Musk just tweeted: ${url}**)
}).catch(err => {
console.log(err)
})
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
})
})
client.login(TOKEN)
```

there is more code above it but its from another thing

I tried this and it doesnt work:

```
function isReply(tweet) {
if ( tweet.retweeted_status
|| tweet.in_reply_to_status_id
|| tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str
|| tweet.in_reply_to_user_id
|| tweet.in_reply_to_user_id_str
|| tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name )
return
}
```

Comment: "This is my code it works but it doesnt do the thing" what's the thing? Also what went wrong with what you tried? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry, if I don't get it right, but for sending tweets (not replies) you need this code: `T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)})`. As you can see it posts "hello world!". Here is [a github repository](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) with code sampes for different goals

Comment: @Lioness100 the thing is to send only tweets and not the replies etc. And no i dont get any error idk

Comment: @chmsv wdym what do i have to do then? And i want to do this: When i send a tweet on twitter then the bot send the twit to discord

Comment: @chmsv oops sorry i didint read ur msg